# Excel, count how many consecutive months

Tags: excel, formula

I have raw data where someone turns up multiple times each month, and over more than one month. I want to know how many months in a row (dating back from today) that person has a value of 0. How do I write a formula for that?

> COUNTIF(s) PERSON IN A2 is found in RAWDATA and VALUE of SCORE COLUMN IN RAW DATA is ZERO and COUNT OF MONTHS IN A ROW FROM TODAY THAT IT IS ZERO"

Person A has score of Zero in May, April, in March and Febuary, so the result should be 4 (count from max date and back)

```
Name    Date    Score
Person A    1/10/2017   1
Person A    1/20/2017   1
Person A    1/30/2017   1
Person A    1/31/2017   1
Person A    2/10/2017   1
Person A    2/20/2017   0
Person A    2/24/2017   1
Person A    2/28/2017   0
Person A    3/10/2017   1
Person A    3/20/2017   1
Person A    3/31/2017   0
Person A    2017-04-31  0
Person A    4/10/2017   1
Person A    4/20/2017   1
Person A    4/28/2017   1
Person A    5/28/2017   0
Person A    5/10/2017   1
Person A    5/26/2017   1
Person A    5/10/2017   1
Person A    5/19/2017   1
Person A    5/30/2017   1
Person A    11/3/2016   1
Person A    11/11/2016  0
Person A    11/22/2016  1
Person A    12/9/2016   1
Person A    12/9/2016   1
Person A    12/19/2016  1
Person A    12/16/2016  1
Person A    2/10/2017   N/A
Person A    2/20/2017   1
Person A    2/24/2017   1
Person A    3/10/2017   1
Person A    3/20/2017   1
Person A    3/28/2017   N/A
Person A    4/20/2017   N/A
Person A    4/25/2017   N/A
Person A    5/30/2017   N/A
Person A    11/28/2016  N/A
Person A    12/6/2016   1
```

Comment: I should think you would search back for the latest date that the person does turn up and work it out from that. Can you give us some data to work on plz? Are you counting complete calendar months?

Comment: Example https://1drv.ms/x/s!At9V0kAWJbEAdA9xRb8FDqRii60

Comment: The example is from excel online.

Comment: Thanks - quite tricky but will have a think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely quite tricky.

My proposed solution is:

```
(a) Find the date D1 of the  latest zero score

(b) Going back month by month from D1, find the latest month which does not contain a zero score.
```

(a) is straightforward - use aggregate to find the latest date when person A has a score of zero

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,RawData!$C$2:$C$100/((RawData!$A$2:$A$100=$A$2)*(RawData!$D$2:$D$100=0)),1)
```

(b) is more difficult. I had to develop an array of months then use COUNTIFS to see how many zero scores for person A fell in each month then use MATCH to see how far back the latest month with no zero scores was. So if you wanted to go back for a year say

```
=MATCH(0,COUNTIFS(RawData!$C$2:$C$100,"<"&DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-ROW($1:$12)+1,1),
RawData!$C$2:$C$100,">="&DATE(YEAR($B2),MONTH($B2)-ROW($1:$12),1),RawData!$A$2:$A100,$A2,RawData!$D$2:$D$100,0),0)
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Note that my dates are in column C because I had to convert them into dd-mm-yyyy and my scores are in column D.

[image]